# Get settings from configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, settings, configuration-files, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to setup MailKit in ASP.NET Boilerplate to send emails, but I keep getting this exception although I have added the settings in the **app.config** file.

Code to send email:

```
_emailSender.Send(
    to: "*****@gmail.com",
    subject: "You have a new task!",
    body: $"A new task is assigned for you: <b>Create doFramework</b>",
    isBodyHtml: true
);
```

Exception received:

> {Abp.AbpException: Setting value for 'Abp.Net.Mail.DefaultFromAddress'
>   is null or empty!    at
>   Abp.Net.Mail.EmailSenderConfiguration.GetNotEmptySettingValue(String
>   name) in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Net\Mail\EmailSenderConfiguration.cs:line
>   44    at Abp.Net.Mail.EmailSenderBase.NormalizeMail(MailMessage mail)
>   in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Net\Mail\EmailSenderBase.cs:line
>   96    at Abp.Net.Mail.EmailSenderBase.Send(MailMessage mail, Boolean
>   normalize) in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Net\Mail\EmailSenderBase.cs:line
>   73    at TaskManagmentApp.Tasks.TaskAppService.GetAll(GetAllTasksInput
>   input) in
>   C:\Users\Dopravo\source\repos\doFramework\SampleProjects\TaskManagmentApp\src\TaskManagmentApp.Application\Services\TaskAppService.cs:line
>   36    at
>   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ITaskAppService_GetAll.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()    at
>   Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformSyncUow(IInvocation
>   invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options) in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkInterceptor.cs:line
>   68    at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()    at
>   Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.PerformSyncAuditing(IInvocation
>   invocation, AuditInfo auditInfo) in
>   D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Auditing\AuditingInterceptor.cs:line
>   51}

**app.config** file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Abp.Net.Mail.DefaultFromAddress" value="lkaddoura@dopravo.com"/>
    <add key="Abp.Net.Mail.DefaultFromDisplayName" value="Lutfi Kaddoura"/>
  </appSettings>     
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to read the settings by implementing my own SettingStore that read from the config file. note that the GetAllListAsync call would need to be implemented.

```
   public class MySettingStore : ISettingStore
    {
        public Task CreateAsync(SettingInfo setting)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task DeleteAsync(SettingInfo setting)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<List<SettingInfo>> GetAllListAsync(int? tenantId, long? userId)
        {
            var result = new List<SettingInfo>();
            var keys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys;

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                result.Add(new SettingInfo(null, null, key, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }

        public Task<SettingInfo> GetSettingOrNullAsync(int? tenantId, long? userId, string name)
        {
            var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[name];

            if (value == null)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<SettingInfo>(null);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(new SettingInfo(tenantId, userId, name, value));
        }

        public Task UpdateAsync(SettingInfo setting)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The MySettingStore would need to be replaced in the PreInitalize() of the module.

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<ISettingStore, MySettingStore>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
}
```

Comment: You mean subclassing `SettingStore` didn't work for you?

Comment: i a way. its just that the SettingStore form the Zero Module didn't workout for me. i would say the answer that i finally posted is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [Setting Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management):

> The **ISettingStore** interface must be implemented in order to use the setting system. While you can implement it in your own way, it's fully implemented in the **Module Zero** project. If it's not implemented, settings are read from the application's **configuration file** (web.config or app.config) but those settings cannot be changed. Scoping will also not work.

To fallback on configuration file, subclass `SettingStore` and override `GetSettingOrNullAsync`:

```cs
public class MySettingStore : SettingStore
{
    public MySettingStore(
        IRepository<Setting, long> settingRepository,
        IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager)
        : base(settingRepository, unitOfWorkManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<SettingInfo> GetSettingOrNullAsync(int? tenantId, long? userId, string name)
    {
        return base.GetSettingOrNullAsync(tenantId, userId, name)
            ?? DefaultConfigSettingStore.Instance.GetSettingOrNullAsync(tenantId, userId, name);
    }
}
```

Then replace `ISettingStore` in your module:

```cs
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<ISettingStore, MySettingStore>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
}
```